python, Typer: disable printing of elements such as the traceback and locals
I am using Typer and it looks pretty cool.
However in a particular case, I want to hide some details for being print. In particular consider a case like
import typer
app = typer.Typer()

@app.command()
def connect_to_super_secret_server():
  host = os.env.get(HOST,'foohost')
  port = ...
  password = ...
  username = ...
  ....
  assert error_foobar_did_not_happen, "FooBar must be set."
  ...
  return connection

When the assertion triggers an exception, I am getting something like:
╭─────────────────────────────── Traceback (most recent call last) ────────────────────────────────╮
│ ..............
│ ..............
│ ..Huge traceback.
│ ..............
│ ..............
│ ..............
│ ..............
│ ..............
│ ..............
│ ..............
│ ..............
│                                                                                                  │
│ ╭──────── locals ────────╮                                                                       │
│ │    host  = 'localhost' │                                                                       │
│ │ password = sensitive   │                                                                       │
│ │     port = 9200        │                                                                       │
│ │ username = 'admin'     │                                                                       │
│ ╰────────────────────────╯                                                                       │
╰──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────╯
AssertionError: FooBar must be set

The traceback is really cool when developing, but would it be possible to disable in production?
Also, most importantly, would there be a way to hide the value of the sensitive password variable so as not to print it in plaintext?

Did you look here: https://typer.tiangolo.com/tutorial/exceptions/? Also note the mentioned environment variable at the end.

Ah, actually thanx, that solves how to hide locals (though it hides ALL of them by app = typer.Typer(pretty_exceptions_show_locals=False)) pretty_exceptions_show_locals=False) on the other hand makes the traces even larger if I ever want more details :)

The solution I ended up using was to explicitly use a try clause
and then exit with an error code:
try:
  ...
except:
  typer.secho("Error: Could not connect to Server", fg=typer.colors.RED, bold=True)
  raise typer.Exit(code=1)  

This will stop any stack tracing... etc. from being printed.
However, there should be another solution as well, combining the suggestion of
@Leander by
app = typer.Typer(pretty_exceptions_show_locals=False)

With changing the trace handler based on this question's answer: Hide traceback unless a debug flag is set
Notice that for python 3 sys.tracebacklimit seems do nothing, one has to go with the exception handler.
